# Conexión FTP - OutputStream en null

Tags: java, ftp, websphere, ftpclient

Gente, soy nuevo en conexiones del FTP. De manera local el código me va excelente pero cuando lo subo al servidor de aplicaciones de mi empresa precisamente en la linea del OutputStream va nulo. Crea el archivo en el FTP pero no escribe. ¿Alguna idea de que pueda ser? Se los agradezco.

```
try {
        ftpClient.connect(ftpDataBaseServer);
        ftpClient.login(ftpDataBaseUsername, ftpDataBasePassword);
        log.info("Conectado a " + ftpDataBaseServer);
        log.info(ftpClient.getReplyString());
        int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply) && bufferedReader!=null) {
            log.info("Inicia envio archivo solicitudCorreos.txt" );
            OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream(ftpDataBaseFilename);
            log.info("OutputStream-----> " + os);
            os.write(archivoDirecciones.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            ftpClient.logout();
            log.info("Finaliza envio archivo " + ftpDataBaseFilename);  

        } else {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            log.error("El servidor rechazo la conexion, o el archivo esta vacio");
            error= 1;
         }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
          log.error(ioe);
          error= 2;
    } finally {
        if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                log.info("Desconectado de " + ftpDataBaseServer);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
        }

    }
```

**Log**

> [5/8/18 10:25:58:113 CST] 0000021d FTPDAOImpl    I xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.dao.impl.FTPDAOImpl agregarArchivo Inicia envio archivo solicitudCorreos.txt
>   [5/8/18 10:25:58:124 CST] 0000021d FTPDAOImpl    I xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.dao.impl.FTPDAOImpl agregarArchivo OutputStream-----> null
>   [5/8/18 10:25:58:126 CST] 0000021d FTPDAOImpl    I xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.dao.impl.FTPDAOImpl agregarArchivo Desconectado de 10.149.128.22
>   [5/8/18 10:25:58:142 CST] 0000021d ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause xxxxx: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debo insertar las siguientes lineas de código:

```
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();   
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com), si eres nuevo, realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), también te recomiendo, que visites [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular de manera correcta las preguntas, para que estas reciban respuesta; ademas de ser útiles para otras personas.